# Does countable union of translation of open sets cover whole $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{\mathcal{O}_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of open subsets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose there exists a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ with finite positive Lebesgue measure $0<|A|<+\infty$, such that $\mathcal{O}_n\supseteq A$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $\{r_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (for concreteness, you may assume that they're the rational points), then:

> **Question**: Is it true that
> \begin{align}
> \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\mathcal{O}_n+r_n)=\mathbb{R}^d?
> \end{align}

At first I thought that *any* sequence of open sets will do the job, but soon I recall the standard example that if $\mathcal{O}_n$ is an open ball of radius $2^{-n}$, then by the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure, the L.H.S. has only finite Lebesgue measure and hence cannot be equal to $\mathbb{R}^d$. Apparently this example fails because the measure $|\mathcal{O}_n|$ can be as small as possible, which creates the possibility that their infinite sum is finite. So I thought next that a positive lower bound on the measure; i.e. assume that $\exists c>0$ such that
\begin{align}
|\mathcal{O}_n|\geq c
\end{align}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, could solve the problem. But then choosing $\mathcal{O}_n=B(-r_n,1)$ to be the open ball of radius $1$ centered at $-r_n$ immediately gives a counterexample, since in this case $\mathcal{O}_n+r_n=B(0,1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This example fails because the open sets are "wandering" around as $n$ changes. Consequently, I imposed a stronger condition that $\mathcal{O}_n\supseteq A$ for some $A$ with $|A|>0$. This guarantees both that

- the measures $|\mathcal{O}_n|$ have a positive lower bound (namely, $|A|$); and
- the open sets $\mathcal{O}_n$ are not "wandering" around; they are "centered" at $A$.

but now neither could I prove the equality nor provide a counterexample.

---

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any comment or answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\{r_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of all rational numbers. Consider $A = [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathcal{O}_n = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-r_n\}$ for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then clearly
$$A = [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-r_n\} = \mathcal{O}_n$$
for each $n$. On the other hand
$$0\not \in  r_n + \mathcal{O}_n$$
for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and hence
$$0\not \in \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(r_n + \mathcal{O}_n\right)$$
Thus $\mathbb{R} \neq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\left(r_n + \mathcal{O}_n\right)$.

Comment: Thanks. Deleting $-r_n$ is a clever step to me. Indeed a nice counterexample. =)

Comment: Your question is interesting.